# su - user not landing in users home directory

Tags: shell, prompt, su

One one system when I run `su - otrs` the returned prompt looks like this:

```
[root@some_server admin_app2]# su - otrs
Last login: Thu Jan 31 10:47:37 CET 2019 on pts/0
[otrs@some_server ~]$
```

On another:

```
[root@some_server admin_app2]# su - otrs
Last login: Thu Jan 31 10:47:37 CET 2019 on pts/0
-bash-4.2$
```

## EDIT1

In fact in the second example I land in the otrs home dir but wjat's wrong with  `-bash-4.2$` being displayed insted of  `[otrs@some_server ~]$` ?

## EDIT2

```
[root@some_server admin_app2]# echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
[root@some_server admin_app2]# bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Comment: What is the result of command `pwd` on second server?

Comment: @RomeoNinov Thank you! Please see me edit.

Comment: A assume you don't use something like LDAP or other backends? If that's true, you could compare the output of `grep otrs /etc/passwd` on both machines. Especially the last field is relevant, it shows the login destination for that user.

Comment: The different prompt does not mean that you are not in your home directory. What is the value of variable `PS1`? Do you set `PS1` somewhere in `.profile`, `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile`, `.bash_login`, `/etc/profile`, `/etc/bash.bashrc`?

Answer (score 2):

You can get how variable `PS1` is defined on first server (in files `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile`, `.bash_login`) and copy this setting to the second machine.

Comment: `echo $PS1` gives [\u@\h \W]\$ as result on both.

Comment: Check the versions of `bash` and the default shell: `echo $SHELL`

Comment: It's same on both. Please see my EDIT2

Comment: @blablatrace, check the exact record in `.bashrc` , etc files. They may differ by one symbol

Comment: ok can confirm that this happens only for the `otrs` user. other users get the normal prompt

Answer (score 1):

Kindly check whether home directory of otrs  exsists or not

if home directory doesnt exsists it will switch user but wont jump to the home directory of user

Comment: good idea, but it does :/

Comment: Did you read my comment?

Comment: @eblock yes put this does not apply unfortunately. `otrs` is a local user not managed via ldap.